# Prove the convergence of the integration

Tags: calculus

Prove the convergence of the following function, given $n > 1$.

> $$\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{x \log(1+\frac{1}{x})^n} dx$$

My approach: by changing variable $x \to 1/x$, we will have

$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ x\log^n(1+x)}dx$$

By using the infinite sum, we will have

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i \log^n(1+i)}$$

Then we can use comparison test (the term in the sum is indeed logrithmatically smaller than $1/i$ so it will converges) to conclude the integration converges.

Question: Is my apporoach right? or do I need to change it. I have not done basic calculus for a while. Sorry for asking the simple question.

Comment: Where did $n>1$ get used?

Comment: @zhw. I am not sure.

Comment: Here's the thing: If $n=1,$ thaat series diverges. If $n>1$ it converges. but how do you show that? you look at the integral, which is the very thing we're trying to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Note that

$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ x\log^n(1+x)}dx = \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x+1}{x}\frac{1}{(x+1) \log^n(1+x)}dx.$$

The factor $(x+1)/x$ is bounded above by $2,$ so you can ignore it. Now let $u=\log x.$

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is I do not know whether $\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x) \log^n(x)}dx$ is convergent or not. LOL

Comment: What I'm suggesting will prove that it does.

Comment: But what was wrong in my approach? I mean if we want use integration test by using the sum.